# Bootstrap: Dropdown child element without dropdowning parent element on navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar menu. And My content is: "Menu Item" and "Dropdown Item"

In responsive mode, I want to reach "Dropdown Item" content without, opening "Menu Item"

**My code:**

```
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-toggle">Menu</button>

      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2" class="navbar-toggle">Dropdown Item Content</button>        

      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>

    </div>


    <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown Item <b class="caret"></b></a>

            <ul id="navbar-collapse-2" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>text</li>
            </ul>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>


</div>
```

**

**jsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/mj8qgakz/

**

-- See in responsive mode:
When I click "Menu" and after click "Dropdown Item Content" content is opening.

I want to achieve the same without clicking "Menu"

Is it possible in bootstrap?

Comment: Could you check my answer and let me know if it works for you ?

Comment: did my answer help you ?

Comment: no. What I want is in responsive mode, when I click "Dropdown Item Content" I want to see "text"

Comment: Actually I want it to open as a dropdown under "Dropdown Item Content"

Comment: Did my answer work for you ?

Comment: @AmitJS94, thanks for interest. I'm afraid it didn't help. click your jsFiddle link. then click "Dropdown Item Content" there. nothing happens. I want it to work, thats all. greetings.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to hide the menu item on the phone, something like:

```
<li class="dropdown hidden-xs"><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
```

if i understood the question... not sure

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript or jquery to handle this.It can be achieved by using CSS only.

Here is the updated fiddle : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitjsguy/mj8qgakz/2/)

You can add this media query to your css to control the dropdown menu below `600px` :

```
@media(max-width:600px){
  .dropdown-menu{
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:transparent;
    box-shadow:none;
    border:0;
    margin-left:1em;
  }
  .caret{
    display:none;
  }
}
```